# announcement of deprecated products or services

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Refer to 7.2 Deprecation Policy. Google will announce if it intends to discontinue or make backwards incompatible changes to the Services specified at the URL in the next sentence. Google will use commercially reasonable efforts to continue to operate those Services versions and features identified at https://cloud.google.com/terms/deprecation without these changes for at least one year after that announcement, unless (as Google determines in its reasonable good faith judgment)

Question, what is the announcement will be made? Is it email notice to project owner, or announcement on official website?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you are being affected by the deprecation of a GCP tool, the project owner gets an email mentioning what they are going to be affected by as well as some guidance to be able to decrease the impact of that.

Also, they make an announcement on the documentation with the dates in which they plan to deprecate the tools. Something like [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/deprecation-notice) is usually added.

Hope you find this useful!